# how to use qgamma in R

Tags: r, gamma-distribution

The gamma distribution with a shape parameter k and a scale parameter theta is defined by [image]=  [image]

In **R** If I want to find the quantile at 0.05 probability for a gamma distribution  with Gamma(10,0.5)

I used

```
> qgamma(0.05,shape=10,scale=0.5)
[1] 2.712703
```

but this is not the value I want. The desired value I get when I use,

```
qgamma(0.05,10,0.5)
[1] 10.85081
```

So what is the difference of `qgamma(0.05,10,0.5)` and `qgamma(0.05,shape=10,scale=0.5)`.
Why do I get two completely different results?

Comment: How about to read the help page before asking here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
     qgamma(x,shape,rate,scale=1/rate)
    #here when we use it as a process
    qgamma(0.05,10,0.5)
    #it takes 0.5 as a rate but not as a scale
    qgamma(0.05,shape=10,scale=1/0.5)
    #here 1/0.5 is a scale value but  not rate
    qgamma(0.05,10,shape=1/0.5)
    10.85081
    qgamma(0.05,10,0.5)
    10.85081
```

Answer (score 5):

Read the help page: Scales is the fourth parameter of `qgamma`. The third parameter is `rate = 1/shape`. If you want to call `qgamma` with positional matching of parameters then it should be:

```
> qgamma(0.05, 10, 1/0.5)
[1] 2.712703
```